# Berliner Weisse on Sierra Mist syrup?

Tags: berliner-weisse, lactobacillus

I have a Berliner Weisse going, the yeast out-paced the lacto (WLP 630). fermentation happened quick (1.030 O.G.) maybe a day. Due to a busy schedule and lazyness it sat on the yeast for 6 weeks, and still had no detectable "sour". I racked it off the yeast into a container(6GL.) previously filled (from the Pepsi Bottling facility, with a couple drops of fluid and a very detectable aroma) with Sierra Mist syrup. Then two weeks later added a vial of white labs straight lacto. I did not take a gravity after the transfer but coming from the primary it was 1.010. It has now been a week since I pitched the lacto and it now has a "layer" on top and a few odd white chunks floating around (solid looking like wax not spores or airy looking, is this a lacto thing or a contamination thing?

Comment: Post a picture of the chunks, please.  Could help in identification.

Comment: UPDATE: I'm pretty sure it was the early stages of lacto pellicle formation. its not so attractive looking now so I did quite a bit of research and looks exactly like a "Lactobacillus pellicle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Berliner at 1.010 will still have plenty of sugars left to feed the pellicle. Unless you see fuzz or smell something off (even for Berliner) then I wouldn't worry.